# installing rails 4.2 on ruby 2.2.0 using RVM generates "Your Ruby version is 2.2.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.5"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm

**This is an update for the problem mentioned below:**

I just found out that there is a Gemfile and Gemfile.lock in the root directory i.e system Home directory, and when ever i create a new gemset i believe it uses this gemfile. After installing rails in a newly created gemset, when check the rails version or try to create a new app, it shows the error `Your ruby version is 2.2.0, but your Gemfile specifies 2.1.5`, cause the Gemfile file in my home directory contains that ruby version, and if delete that Gemfile, and try to create a new rails app, it searches for that Gemfile.

I am current going through a hard time. I was starting a new project in ruby 2.2.0 and rails 4.2.0 and started by creating a gemset using RVM inside my project folder.

1. created gemset.

   ```
   $rvm use ruby-2.2.0@myapp --ruby-version --create
   ```
2. Installed latest rails

   ```
   $gem install rails
   ```
3. After that i checked the rails version just to verify

   ```
   $rails -v
   ```

   but instead i get a notification saying `Your Ruby version in 2.2.0 but your Gemfile specified 2.1.5`. I also don't have my application folder yet, cause i get the same output if i try to `$rails new .`

### Following are the RVM related outputs

- My RVM version is 1.26.10.
- `rvm gemset list`

  ```
  gemsets for ruby-2.2.0 (found in /Users/samy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0)
     (default)
     global
     student-portal
     => myapp
  ```
- `gem list` for global gemset

  ```
  bigdecimal (1.2.7, 1.2.6)
  bundler (1.7.13)
  bundler-unload (1.0.2)
  executable-hooks (1.3.2)
  gem-wrappers (1.2.7)
  io-console (0.4.3)
  json (1.8.2, 1.8.1)
  mini_portile (0.6.2)
  minitest (5.5.1, 5.4.3)
  nokogiri (1.6.6.2)
  power_assert (0.2.2)
  psych (2.0.12, 2.0.8)
  rake (10.4.2)
  rdoc (4.2.0)
  rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
  rvm (1.11.3.9)
  test-unit (3.0.9, 3.0.8)
  ```
- `gem list` for myapp gemset

  ```
  actionmailer (4.2.0)
  actionpack (4.2.0)
  actionview (4.2.0)
  activejob (4.2.0)
  activemodel (4.2.0)
  activerecord (4.2.0)
  activesupport (4.2.0)
  arel (6.0.0)
  bigdecimal (1.2.7, 1.2.6)
  builder (3.2.2)
  bundler (1.7.13)
  bundler-unload (1.0.2)
  erubis (2.7.0)
  executable-hooks (1.3.2)
  gem-wrappers (1.2.7)
  globalid (0.3.2)
  hike (1.2.3)
  i18n (0.7.0)
  io-console (0.4.3)
  json (1.8.2, 1.8.1)
  loofah (2.0.1)
  mail (2.6.3)
  mime-types (2.4.3)
  mini_portile (0.6.2)
  minitest (5.5.1, 5.4.3)
  multi_json (1.10.1)
  nokogiri (1.6.6.2)
  power_assert (0.2.2)
  psych (2.0.12, 2.0.8)
  rack (1.6.0)
  rack-test (0.6.3)
  rails (4.2.0)
  rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
  rails-dom-testing (1.0.5)
  rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.1)
  railties (4.2.0)
  rake (10.4.2)
  rdoc (4.2.0)
  rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
  rvm (1.11.3.9)
  sprockets (2.12.3)
  sprockets-rails (2.2.4)
  test-unit (3.0.9, 3.0.8)
  thor (0.19.1)
  thread_safe (0.3.4)
  tilt (1.4.1)
  tzinfo (1.2.2)
  ```
- `which ruby` gives

  ```
  /Users/samy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby
  ```
- `which rails` gives

  ```
  /Users/samy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@myapp/bin/rails
  ```

  - the file contains

    ```
    #!/usr/bin/env ruby_executable_hooks
    #
    # This file was generated by RubyGems.
    #
    # The application 'railties' is installed as part of a gem, and
    # this file is here to facilitate running it.
    #

    require 'rubygems'

    version = ">= 0"

    if ARGV.first
      str = ARGV.first
      str = str.dup.force_encoding("BINARY") if str.respond_to?               :force_encoding
      if str =~ /\A_(.*)_\z/ and Gem::Version.correct?($1) then
        version = $1
        ARGV.shift
      end
    end

    gem 'railties', version
    load Gem.bin_path('railties', 'rails', version)
    ```

I tried removing and reinstalling RVM but i did not work.

Also i tried making app with ruby 2.1.5 with different gemset and all, but there i get different error when i try to do `rails new app`. i get the `Could not find slop-3.6.0 in any of the sources
Run 'bundle install' to install missing gems.`, but once i do the `bundle install` i cannot run the `rails new app` command as it notifies

```
Can't initialize a new Rails application within the directory 
of another, please change to a non-Rails directory first.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you need any more info i am ready to provide it.

Thanks in advance.
Cheers.

Comment: `ruby '2.1.5' ` is set in your gem file of application

Comment: @Nithin  the problem is i am not able to create a new app with `rails new`. currently i only have two files in the root level of my application folder i.e .ruby-gemset and .ruby-version. .ruby-gemset file has the gemset name, and .ruby-version has ruby-2.2.0 in it.

Comment: @Nithin Is there any other place where the gemfile for the application resides apart from the application folder?

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issues and restarting from scratch using this guide helped a lot. Though it seemed yet another guide, I found it to be a bit more systematic and detailed than the others.

[Rails Apps Guide: Install Ruby on Rails · Ubuntu Linux](http://railsapps.github.io/installing-rails.html)

Alternatively, try [Rails Apps Guide: Updating to Rails 4.2](http://railsapps.github.io/updating-rails.html)

Note:

> Rails is not just a Ruby gem, it is a complex and rapidly evolving
>   ecosystem. It is important to set up your development environment with
>   the most current version of all the gems that are needed for
>   development.